# Getting Exception - No such element found in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML code of Add Button

```
<div id="errorDiv" class="popup" style="display: none;"> 
  <a class="buttom active" href="addEditUser.action">Add</a>
```

I wrote Selenium code using `TestNG` to click on this Add Button.

```
webelement a =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".buttom.active"));
a.click();
```

Getting an exception

> No such element found Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":".buttom.active"}

Comment: Hi, please check if it is inside a iframe or not and also give a try with waits. thanks

Comment: Yes, smells like an iFrame issue to me, too. Your CSS selector is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This might work better for you.  Here I define a flexible locator that uses a *contains* clause:

```
By clickableButton = By.xpath(".//button[contains(@class, 'active')]");
webelement a = driver.findElement(clickableButton);
a.click();
```